# Retrieving index of substrings contained within array

Tags: arrays, ruby, substring

I'm looping over some files, and need to skip files that have a certain substring in their path. These substrings are defined as an array. For example:

```
Dir.glob("#{temp_dir}/**/*").each do |file|
  # Skip files in the ignore list
  if (file.downcase.index("__macosx"))
    next
  end

  puts file
end
```

The code above successfully skips any file path with `__macosx`, but I need to adapt it to work with an array of substrings, something like the following:

```
if (file.downcase.index(["__macosx", ".ds_store"]))
    next
end
```

How can I do that, while avoiding having to write an extra loop to iterate over the substring array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to check like this:

```
ignore_files = %w(__macosx ds_store)
Dir.glob("#{temp_dir}/**/*").each do |file|
  # Skip files in the ignore list
  next if ignore_files.any? { |ignore_file| %r/ignore_file/i =~ file }

  puts file
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Although I think I needed to convert `ignore_file` to a regular expression to use `=~`? The line that works in the end is: `next if Init::IGNORE_PATHS.any? { |ignore_path| /#{ignore_path}/ =~ file.name.downcase }`

Comment: @JohnDorean - yes, good catch.  I updated my answer to use the regex syntax w/ the `i` for case insensitive.

Comment: You could also use a combined regular expression, e.g.  `Regexp.union(Init::IGNORE_PATHS)`